# What does +-- mean in vimdiff output file? How to turn it off?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, diff, vimdiff

I use vimdiff to compare two text files. Each file has around 1000 lines.
The diff works fine. However, it collapses/folds a few "same" lines like below in the output diff file:

```
+--  2 lines: | Opened browser Firefox
CreateTest | Accounts :  -> Button => Save is clicked
+--  8 lines: | CreateTest | Accounts :  -> Button => Search is clicked
```

My vimdiff command is as below:

```
vimdiff file1 file2 -c TOhtml -c  'w! diff_output.html' -c 'qa!'
```

How do I turn this off? I want to see all the lines (even if they are same) in the output diff file, without any automatic folding/collapsing?

EDIT:
I am running this command through a Java project using Runtime.getRuntime().exec() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
vimdiff -c "set foldlevel=9999" file1 file2 -c TOhtml -c  'w! diff_output.html' -c 'qa!'
```

Answer (score 2):

It's folding feature in vim http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_28.html

If you want to turn it off, add another param to change the `foldopen` option.

```
vimdiff file1 file2  -c 'set foldopen=all'
```

Comment: I tried this `vimdiff $MASTERLOGFILE.1 $BUILDLOGFILE.1 -c 'set foldopen=all' -c TOhtml -c  'w! '"$OUTPUTDIFFFILE"'' -c 'qa!'` But, still the HTML file shows a few lines as folded.

Comment: EDIT: I am running this command through a Java project using Runtime.getRuntime().exec() method.

Comment: @InsecureNoob first, try to run `vimdiff $MASTERLOGFILE.1 $BUILDLOGFILE.1 -c 'set foldopen=all'` to see if the option is working. Then you can set it global in `~/.vimrc`. The HTML should be showing as expected.

Comment: But, would we have right access to `~/.vimrc` file via a Java project that runs on multiple machines?

Comment: `-c 'set foldopen=all'` didn't work as expected. It still folds a few lines.

Answer (score 1):

All of the fold commands in vim start with the 'z' key. I believe for undoing all folds you want to type 'zi'.

Also try ":help z"

Comment: EDIT: I am running this command through a Java project using Runtime.getRuntime().exec() method.

Comment: @InsecureNoob If you aren't using vim interactively then why aren't you just using the diff command?

Comment: TOhtml seems to work only for vimdiff and not for diff

Comment: `vimdiff file1 file2 -c TOhtml -c  'w! diff_output.html' -c 'qa!'`